# Linux Mint. How to set the terminal password to be invisible?

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, sudo

I change to Linux Mint about 2 days ago. And I feel uncomfortable when I put the 'sudo password', because I used to see nothing and now I saw "*****".

Comment: Are the asterisks showing up when you run `sudo something`, or when logging in as root, or???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LinuxMint added the behavior in `/etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback`.

You could simply do like I did, delete the file as it contains only that adjustment:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback
```

Comment: See @Entropy0's answer bellow for a more permanent and solid solution.

Comment: @Entropy0's answer should be the accepted answer because it will work after system upgrades. This solution will only work until you upgrade your system.

Answer (score 7):

Use visudo to remove any mention of 'pwfeedback' in your sudoers file.  If on, it's usually under one of the 'Defaults' lines.

You can also add a ! before any instance of pwfeedback in the file to explicitly disable it if you need finer-grain control.

Edit: If you're uncomfortable using vi you can also specify the editor with something like `EDITOR=nano sudo -E visudo`

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer of simply removing `/etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback` will work precisely until the next update to `mintsystem` puts that file back in place.

The way to revert to the old behavior that is [recommended](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=284566#p1572457) by the person responsible for the new one is to override the setting in a different file that gets read later:

```
echo 'Defaults !pwfeedback'|sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/9_no_pwfeedback
```