# Linux Mint 19 Tara - after update sudo is showing stars instead of nothing

Tags: linux-mint, sudo, software-updates

I have Linux Mint 19 Tara and today I installed new updates of packages which you can see below in the picture. After that during `sudo` usage `sudo` shows `*` instead of nothing. Sudo works but this is strange, after I hit enter, stars will disappear.

```
$ sudo echo
[sudo] password for matej: *********
```

Another strange thing is with console, at first open I can write my username but password gets confirmed without my interference. So I can't login to console.

[image: updated packages]

Comment: Take a look at your `/etc/sudoers` file; the update likely added a `pwfeedback` to your `Defaults` section.

Comment: (Reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/387764/619216)

Comment: @JeffSchaller You are right! There is file /etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback and with `ls` I can see today's date. What should I do with this file? Remove it or modify it?

Comment: @JeffSchaller All right, I delted this file but still I can't log in to the console. Any idea?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I googled second bug and I found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873   So thank you very much for solving first problem with `*`!

Comment: Feel free to self-answer with the solutions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After @JeffSchaller directed me to this [password feedback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387757/how-to-make-password-show-asterisks-as-i-type-it-when-running-sudo-command/387764#387764) I found that in `/etc/sudoers.d` is new file named `0pwfeedback` with content `Defaults pwfeedback`. After removing this file, problem with stars in `sudo` was solved.

---

Second problem with login to console is known: [ubuntu bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873) but I am still trying figure out how to solve it.

---

Edit 6.3.2019:

It looks like kernel `4.15.0-46` solved problem with console login. I can now normally login into console and password input is not automatically entered.

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-46-generic
$
```

Answer (score 0):

The change in sudo behavior is actually mentioned in the [release notes of Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa](https://linuxmint.com/rel_tessa_cinnamon_whatsnew.php):

> To prevent you from typing your password into the wrong window (and sending it online by mistake), sudo now shows asterisks when you type your password.

What is not mentioned, however, and I'm not sure whether this was intended, is that it was automatically introduced into 19.0 with a normal update.

If you want to revert the change, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491173/linux-mint-how-to-set-the-terminal-password-to-be-invisible).